# I deleted /opt/homebrew directory via '''sudo rm -r''' and now my computer is completely wiped. How can this be?

Tags: terminal, macos

I was working on downloading iTerm2 on my M1 2020 MacBook and ran into a problem while downloading homebrew. In order to reinstall, I deleted /opt/homebrew directory and now all my files are gone. I have tried to recover those files to no avail. How can this be? Some files like my documents are still there but that is about it.

Comment: If nothing works, please give R-Studio Undelete a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000

Comment: It's a while ago, but what command line did you actually use to try and remove /opt/homebrew?